# Access denied when I run a .cmd file from c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, c#-4.0, iis-7

I have a web application that is hosted on an IIS7 server on a server computer with windows server 2008, the application consists of executing a .cmd file but it shows me the following error

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied
   en System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   en System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   en System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   en Ted.MNSProject.Reiniciar.Shutdown() en C:\Users\test\Desktop\Soluciones\MNS\Ted.MNS\Ted.MNSProject\Reiniciar.aspx.cs:línea 154
   en Ted.MNSProject.Reiniciar.btnSiReiniciar_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) en C:\Users\test\Desktop\Soluciones\MNS\Ted.MNS\Ted.MNSProject\Reiniciar.aspx.cs:línea 59
```

This is my code source

```html
       protected void btnSiReiniciar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Shutdown();

                Log2("MNS OK");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log2("MNS ERROR  " + ex.ToString());
            }

        }



public void Shutdown()
        { 
            string pathBAT = "C:\\Users\\pc1\\Desktop\\restartWindows.cmd";

            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(pathBAT);

            startInfo.Verb = "runas";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);

        }
```

Comment: The error says "Access Denied" to a shutdown function. Is this related to the computer permissions?

Comment: @SunnyPatel Yes, maybe it's the privileges of iis

Comment: Getting access denied in .NET (rather than within `cmd.exe`) likely means the identity executing your .NET code does not have read/execute access to the command file.(And an IIS identity won't normally have the privileged to shutdown/restart Windows either.)

Comment: when I run my application locally if it works but I have the problem when it is on the server

Answer (score 1):

When you deploy it to IIS, then all code would be executed under  "IIS Apppool\" And file like cmd would be reached via your authenticated user like IUSR.

So please try to set your application pool to local system and set anonymous user to application pool identity.
[image]
[image]

If you don't want to use localsystem as app pool identity, please try to troubleshooting this with crash dump and process monitor. It will tell us how to grant permission correctly.